# Find a condition such that $\|f(x)\|_p$ is constant

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $\mu(X)=1$ and $1\leq p\leq\infty$, I'm curious of whether I can find a condition such that $\|f(x)\|_p=C$ for some $C>0$ constant. My initial guess is $|f(x)|$ should be constant $\mu$-almost everywhere.

I'm trying to prove this statement, but I meet some difficulties. Here is what I have so far:

**1.** I can prove that for $1\leq p\leq q\leq\infty$, and $\mu(X)=1$, $\|f\|_p\leq\|f\|_q$ by Holder's inequality.

**2.** I also can show that $\|f\|_p=0$ if and only if $f=0$ almost everywhere.

But I'm not sure whether I can adapt the method from **2** by just replacing $0$ with constant $C>0$. I also tried to use simple functions and a bounded measurable function $h(x)$ s.t. $0\leq h(x)\leq f(x)$ of finite support to $f(x)$ in $L^p$ sense, but it does not work. Can anyone help to write down a proof about this? And how can I extend the result to $p=\infty$? Or if my guess is wrong, can anyone provide a counterexample about this? Thank you.

**Added:**
Let $N=\{x:f(x)\neq C\}$ be a null set. $|f(x)|=C>0$ for all $x\in X\setminus N$.

Note that $|f(x)|=|C\chi_{X\setminus N}+f\chi_{N}|$.

For $1\leq p<\infty$, write $$\|f\|_p^p=\|C\chi_{X\setminus N}\|_p^p+\|f\chi_{N}\|_p^p=|C|^p\mu(X\setminus N)+\|f\|_p^p\mu(N)$$

Since $\mu(X)=1$ and $N$ is a null set, $\mu(X\setminus N)=1$, the second term vanishes. Hence
$$\|f\|_p^p=|C|^p$$
Take power of $1/p$ on both sides,
$$\|f\|_p=C$$

For $p=\infty$, can I use the fact that $\lim_{p\to\infty}\|f(x)\|_p=\|f(x)\|_\infty$ to generalize the result?

Or just simply for the definition of the $\|f\|_\infty=\inf\{C'>0:|f(x)|\leq C'\text{ for a.e. $x$ }\}=C$.

Thanks to @Severin Schraven's suggestions.

Comment: Pick any nonzero function $g$ in $L^p$. Then consider $f=Cg/\Vert g\Vert_p$. What is $\Vert f \Vert_p$?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Is it just the constant $C$? How is it related to my question? I'm not sure whether I understand your hint.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, then you are asking whether $\Vert f \Vert_p=C$ implies that $f(x)=c$ $\mu$-a.e. Then my construction is telling you that that this not true (and that it is difficult to find conditions to ensure $\Vert f \Vert_p=c$).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven No, I'm actually asking the reverse side, whether $f$ is constant $\mu$-a.e. implies $\|f\|_p$ is constant, when $\mu(X)=1$.

Comment: So, what you actually want is: If $\vert f(x)\vert=C$ up to null sets, then $\Vert f\Vert_p=C$ for all $1\leq p\leq \infty$?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Correct! Do you have any approaches on proving this? I've mentioned the two approaches I've tried, but I have little progress, unfortunately.

Comment: Well, let $N$ be a null set such that $f(x)=C$ for $x\in X\setminus N$. Then you have $f= C 1_{X\setminus N} + f 1_N$. We then compute (using that the two functions have disjoint support) $$\Vert f\Vert_p^p = \Vert C 1_{X\setminus N} \Vert_p^p + \Vert f 1_N\Vert_p^p.$$ The first term is equal to$\vert C\vert^p \mu(X\setminus N)=\vert C\vert^p$. As $N$ is a null set, one can show that the second term vanishes. I hope you can fill in the details.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I have added details according to your suggestions in my post. Does the case $p=\infty$ hold? Since $\lim_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_p=\|f\|_\infty$ (I can prove this) holds, can I use this to extend to the infinity case? Thank you.

Comment: Indeed, either you use the limit or use directly the definition of null set and the definition of essential supremum (i.e. the definition of the $L^\infty$-norm).